# How to pass javascript integer variable as primary key into django url with modalForm package

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-urls

I am using DataTables (https://datatables.net/). When each row is clicked, the value of the `ID` column must be passed as a primary key to open an update form.

Everything works fine except for passing the javascript variable into the django URL.

```
var adresid = 0
$('.dt-edit').each(function () {
    $(this).on('click', function(evt){
    $this = $(this);
    adresid = parseInt($this.parents('tr')[0].cells[13].innerHTML)
    })
    .modalForm({
       formURL: "{% url 'adres-update-modal' adresid %}"
    });
});
```

I tried to use the `.replace()` method as `formURL: "{% url 'adres-update-modal' pk %}".replace('pk', adresid)`, but that did not work.

This is the error that I keep getting :

> Reverse for 'adres-update-modal' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1
>   pattern(s) tried: ['adres/(?P[0-9]+)/updatemodal/$']

When I replace `adresid` in the url with an integer (e.g. `16`) everything works perfectly fine.

Any help would be appreciated

EDIT: here is het HTML of my table

```html
 <table id="masterTable" class="table nowrap" style="width:100%">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th></th>
                        <th></th>
                        <th>A</th>
                        <th>B</th>
                        <th>C</th>
                        <th>D</th>
                        <th>E</th>
                        <th>F</th>
                        <th>G</th>
                        <th>H</th>
                        <th style="text-align:center;width:100px;">Add adres <button type="button" data-func="dt-add" class="btn btn-success btn-xs dt-add modal-adres-create">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        </button></th>
                        <th class="none">I</th>
                        <th class="none">J</th>
                        <th class="none">K</th>
                        <th class="none">L</th>
                        <th class="none">M</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    {% for X in Y %}
                    {% for P in Q %}
                    {% if X.Z == U %}
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>A</td>
                        <td>B</td>
                        <td>C</td>
                        <td>D</td>
                        <td>E</td>
                        <td>F</td>
                        <td>G</td>
                        <td>H</td>
                        <td>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs dt-edit" style="margin-right:16px;">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            </button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs dt-delete">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            </button>
                        </td>
                        <td>I</td>
                        <td>J</td>
                        <td>K</td>
                        <td>L</td>
                        <td>M</td>
                    </tr>
                    {% endif%}
                    {% endfor %}
                    {% endfor %}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

EDIT 2: To clarify, when I use `console.log(adresid)` it does return an integer with the value of `16`. So therefore I do not expect the problem to be anywhere else than in the javascript part where this value has to be passed to the `formURL` value.

Comment: Please show the html code where you show the elements

Comment: @AmineMessaoudi, I added the HTML Table code. I was under the impression that because if I replace ```adresid``` with ```16``` and everything works that this part was not important. Apologies if I was wrong about that. I hope you can come up with something :)

Comment: In the foor loop you are just displaying A, B, C..... You need to display Django variables using the `{{ var }}` notation. I guess this is the problem because you didn't set the id from django and thats why its empty. You need to do something like this `<td> {{X.id}} </td>`.

Comment: @AmineMessaoudi that is all irrelevant. OP is trying to look up a URL once and then customise it in JavaScript. The structure of the HTML has nothing to do with anything.

Comment: @NinjaChris can you please post a screenshot of the table shown ? You are accessing row 13 so maybe it has a value which is not a valid integer

Comment: @AmineMessaoudi Thanks for your comment. I am indeed using django values. The A B C values I just put in here to prevent posting sensitive information. The ```adresid``` variable did return an integer so therefore I assumed that the whole html code was not necessary to check anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `adresid = parseInt($this.parents('tr')[0].cells[13].innerHTML)` is returning the required value, I would have expected the `modalForm` method to be situated inside the `on` callback, something like this:

```
$('.dt-edit').each(function () {
  $(this).on('click', function(evt){
    $this = $(this);
    adresid = parseInt($this.parents('tr')[0].cells[13].innerHTML);
    $('.adres-update-modal').modalForm({
       formURL: "{% url 'adres-update-modal' adresid %}"
    });
  });
});
```

That would be the only way to get the correct value for the clicked row

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately your suggestion did not work. It still returns the same error message ```Reverse for 'adres-update-modal' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['adres/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/updatemodal/$']```